# Storing a structure field into a vector

Tags: python, structure

I have code that solves the assignment problem in Python using Google-OR Solver. Since I am new to Python, I need bit of help in storing variables in the usual vector form rather than the complicated structure-field form.

```
for i in range(0, assignment.NumNodes()):
    print('Worker %d assigned to task %d.  Cost = %d' % (i,assignment.RightMate(i), assignment.AssignmentCost(i)))
```

what i want to do this i just want the two arrays of 'Workers' and 'Task'. For workers It is obvious that it will be 0 to last one, but i also need the vector of indices of Tasks. How do I store this

```
'assignment.RightMate()'
```

values in a single vector and print just those values

Comment: Are you trying to create a list (i.e. vector) composed of `assignment.RightMate(i)` for the different values of i?

Comment: Yes, i want all the values of assignment.RightMate(i) from i=0,1,2......end, into a vector/list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [list comprehension](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-list-comprehension) to get all values of assignment.RightMate()

```
assignment_list = [assignment.RightMate(i) for i in range(assignment.NumNodes()]
```

For workers you simply have:

```
worker_list = list(range(assignment.NumNodes()))
```

**Explanation**

The list comprehension is equivalent to the following for loop (which is an alternative method of doing this):

```
assignment_list = []
for i in range(assignment.NumNodes()):
  assignment_list.append(assignment.RightMate(i))
```

Note range() starts at 0 by default so:

```
range(0, X) is equivalent to range(X)
```